# BLAZOR : Onclick event fired automatically when with component base class model

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am having a razor page as below. its inheriting the PaymentBase class that is having the code behind codes..

```
@page "/payment"
@inherits PaymentBase

<h1>Payments</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@GetList()">List all payments</button>
```

The `GetList` function is fired automatically once the page is rendered and not on the click event..
any help please ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
onclick="@GetList()"
```

The above code is executed when your component is being rendered because the instruction `@GetList()` is evaluated to execution of `GetList` the result of which is assigned to the `onclick` attribute of the button element.

Note: onclick is an attribute of the button element, but `@onclick` is a compiler directive attribute instructing the compiler to create an `EventCallback` 'delegate' which encapsulates the method whose name provided as value to this attribute.

Always use the pattern: `@onclick="<MethodName>"`

Note that the following code is legitimate, but not recommended as it combines C# and JavaScript unnecessarily: `onclick="window.prompt('Enter you name...')"`

Hope this helps...

Comment: How would you pass parameter to the function in this case?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Found the answer.
One would use lamda expression to pass parameter to a function.
@onclick=(() => GetList(parameter))

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a function, not call the function.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetList">List all payments</button>
```

By doing `@onclick="GetList"` you pass a function to `onclick`, by doing `@onclick="GetList()"` you are calling `GetList` and passing the return of `GetList()` to the `onclick`.

Also don't forget to add `@` before the `onclick`.

Comment: with your solution i am getting "The name onclick does not exist in the current context", and for the function name its complaining "Missing attribute name"
Note: I am calling function in the code behind file C# , not in the razor page itself

Comment: @surajsingh sorry, my mistake, please take a look at my answer, now it should work

Comment: @surajsingh what version is blazor and  .net are you using?